# How can get html content include content of javascript?

Tags: java, http

i need to get contents on web page and read it via URL,but contents not include data on javascript any body can help me to solve this problem ? For example : i want to get bibtext content ' javascrip from URL : http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=152610.152611&coll=DL&dl=GUIDE&CFID=111326695&CFTOKEN=18291914 how can i get content (2) from (1)[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a quick observation, here is what I would do:

1/ Get the content of this web page: http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=152610.152611&coll=DL&dl=GUIDE&CFID=111326695&CFTOKEN=18291914

2/ Use regular expression to search for 'BibTeX' and locate the below string in the content:

```
<li style="list-style:disc; display:inline; margin-bottom:0px;"><a href="javascript:ColdFusion.Window.show('theformats');ColdFusion.navigate('exportformats.cfm?id=152611&amp;expformat=bibtex','theformats');" class="small-link-text">BibTeX</a></li>
```

3/ Use another regular expression to fish out:

```
exportformats.cfm?id=152611&amp;expformat=bibtex
```

4/ Concatenate it to the url (make sure you decode `&amp;` to &):

"http://portal.acm.org/" + "exportformats.cfm?id=152611&expformat=bibtex"

5/ Capture the content you're looking for. Ultimately http://portal.acm.org/exportformats.cfm?id=152611&expformat=bibtex gives you the content.

Comment: This regular expression will work for step 3 (and you can skip step 2): regex = "(exportformats[.]cfm.+bibtex)"